# Different language for browser and system in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, language, internet-explorer-10

In Windows 8 it is possible to download multiple language packs. I'm running Windows in English but I'd like to set Dutch as the primary language/culture for Internet Explorer 10.
As soon as I move Dutch to the top of the list, it will also become the default language for Windows.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer just by clicking around a bit longer:

1. In the **Control Panel**, click **Clock, Language and Region** and then click **Language**
2. Click **Advanced Settings** in the menu on the left
3. In the section **Override for Windows display language**, select the language that you want to use as the display language
4. Click the Save button and press the back button (ALT + Left arrow or backspace) to return to the Language preferences window
5. Now make sure that the language that you would like to use as the locale in Internet Explorer is on top of the list

You might have to logout and login to enable these settings.